# threejs export child pos and rot

Tags: three.js

I am exporting position and rotation of children from threejs and noticed that they all seem wrong. Here is an example of how it look sin threejs

and here is how it looks when the same objects are imported in Blender with the given position and rotation

For many reasons, I am not exporting a full .gltf or .obj file but just the transformation data. Here is the function:

```
scene.traverse(function(child){
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh){                       
        child.updateMatrixWorld();
        const rotMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
        child.matrixWorld.extractRotation(rotMat);
        var the_world_pos = new THREE.Vector3();
        var the_world_rot = new THREE.Euler();
        child.getWorldPosition(the_world_pos);                   
        the_world_rot.setFromRotationMatrix(rotMat);
        exportTokenToTxt(// another function to export to a txt file
                         child.name,
                         child.material.name,                                                                                                                     
                     [the_world_pos.x,the_world_pos.y,the_world_pos.z],                                                                                               
                     [the_world_rot.x,the_world_rot.y,the_world_rot.z]
                        );
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Is the camera in both 'worlds' set to the same position and rotation?

Comment: I am trying to get the world coordinates and rotations correctly. So, normally the camera is not involved in this. The two screenshots taken are not exactly from the same point of view. They just quickly show the two parts are not at the same position and rotation in the two worlds.